# fadeOut and fadeIn Div When Clicking Checkbox or its label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to fadeOut if the checkbox is unchecked, and fadeIn if the checkbox is checked. Also I have the label clickable so the text next to the checkbox should ideally do the same. Heres what I have so far, it doesn't work but I'm not sure why:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frequent1').on('change', function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#self").fadeOut;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="frequent1" name="frequent1" value="self" checked> This
    item: </label>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML markup.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Check the console for errors, and tell us if there is any

Comment: Where's the element with the ID of self? `$("#self")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fadeOut is a jQuery function.

This:

`$("#self").fadeOut;`

needs to be this:

`$("#self").fadeOut();`

Answer (score 1):

Do some corrections in your code,

1. create an element with `id="self"`
2. fadeOut and fadeIn are not the properties, they are method in jQuery, so use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frequent1').on('change', function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            $("#self").fadeOut();
        }
        else{
          $("#self").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="frequent1" name="frequent1" value="self" checked> <span id="self">This item: </span>
    </label>
```